# SharePoint Site Collections Planning

Tags: site-collection, design

I'm a SharePoint newbie and I am wondering the best way to design SP web application. There are 2 departments- Dept A takes customer data, Dept B analyses customer data.

1. Can I create 2 site collections like this- `company.com/sites/customerInfo` and `company.com/sites/customerAnalyse`?
2. Can `company.com/sites/customerAnalyse` access data from `company.com/sites/customerInfo`? If so, how? (Data will be likely stored in list or document library.)

EDIT: There will be one document library which collects all customer transactions. The documents uploaded are for documentation only. But the doc properties like customer name, region, dollar amount etc will be used for customer analysis (Lets call this Company Customer Data). This 'Company Customer Data' will be compared against 'External Customer Data' that will come from an external data source (i.e. another database on same SQL server as that of SharePoint) and analysed. Will likely use Microsoft BI tools.

Comment: Will there be lots of lists? Will the customer data be an aggregation of collected data stored in many lists into one? How does the Analyzers expect to access the customer data? You say data will likely be stored in Lists or Doc Libraries - will there be actual documents (Word, Excel etc.) attached to customer data? Please elaborate on the bigger picture of this.

Comment: what type of the data and analyse will be perfomed on the data? is there any tool you using for analyzing the data or any BI tools etc?

Comment: I have answered your questions as an EDIT to OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle you have three alternatives:

1) Two site collections

2) A site collection with two sites

3) A site collection with a site

In option 1 the information is completely separate and permissions as well. It will be very difficult to access information from another, except for programming. I do not recommend it.

In option two you can manage permissions for each site well. But it is not easy to access information from another site without programming. Something you can do with SharePoint Designer and content types and site columns.

In the last option will be more difficult to manage permissions. But it is easier to access information using configuration only.

To answer your question:

1) You can create two collections
2) 2) But it will be virtually impossible to read information from towards each other

It is difficult to recommend something with the little information I have. 2) But it will be virtually impossible to read information from towards each other